# DISTINCT COLUMN VALUES FROM ANOTHER TABLE IN JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select t1.key,t2.design,t1.price,t1.gender,t1.store
from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.key=t2.key;
```

This is my query. In this query, column KEY is distinct. I need result with distinct DESIGN values. Help me with this.

Comment: NEED RESULT WITH NO DUPLICATES IN DESIGN.

Comment: An example of the data you are dealing with would be useful, also what RDMS are you using?

Comment: KEY|DESIGN|PRICE|GENDER|STORE| 1234|eo234|100|m|hyd  database is oracle.

Comment: That is not data. We need to see values like 1 or "Abc" when we say data.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(1), COUNT(t1.key), COUNT(t2.design)
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2  WHERE t1.KEY = t2.KEY; When i do this i get the result as --  4000|4000|3000| . So in this case i need 3000 records only.

Comment: please provide table structure.

Comment: In brief tell me what all u need to go ahead. thanks

Comment: There are 2 tables, from those two tables i'm picking all the columns from one table and one column from another, for this i'm performing join and everything went well.but as of now i need unique values in that one column(no duplicates).

Comment: Use group by & aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key
where design like "specific design"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not precise. There are two things possible:

1) You are talking about duplicate records, i.e. for two records with the same design the columns key, price, gender and store are guaranteed to be equal. Two ways to solve it:

```
select DISTINCT t1.key,t2.design,t1.price,t1.gender,t1.store
from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.key=t2.key;
```

or

```
select t1.key,t2.design,t1.price,t1.gender,t1.store
from table1 t1, (select distinct key, design from table2) t2
where t1.key=t2.key;
```

2) You are talking of duplicate designs and ambigious information related, i.e. for two records for the same design you may get different prices etc. Then you must think about what information you want to get per design. The maximum price? The sum of prices? ...

```
select t1.key,t2.design,sum(t1.price),max(t1.gender),max(t1.store)
from table1 t1,table2 t2
where t1.key=t2.key
group by t1.key,t2.design;
```

This gives you records per key and design. If you want records per design only then you would group only by design and decide which key you want to show with it.

A last recommendation: Use explicit join syntax. It is easier to read and less error-prone.

```
select t1.key, t2.design, t1.price, t1.gender, t1.store
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.key = t2.key;
```

Comment: 1) FOR THE 1ST QUERY ERROR IS INVALID IDENTIFIER. 2) ERROR IS NOT A SINGLE GROUP BY FUNCTION. 3) IS THE SAME JOIN AS I DID.     I NEED TO REMOVE DUPLICATES FROM DESIGN BEFORE FINAL EXTRACT. TABLE 1 HAS 20 COLUMNS AND TABLE 2 HAS 25 COLUMNS. MY QUERY IS TO PULL ALL 20 COLUMNS FROM TABLE 1 AND ONE COLUMN FROM TABLE 2 BY SIMPLE JOIN BASED ON BOTH PRODUCT_KEY'S WHICH ARE PRIMARY KEYS. MY EXTRACT SHOULD NOT HAVE DUPLICATES IN THAT ONE PARTICULAR COLUMN FROM TABLE 2. I HOPE THIS CLARIFIES YOU.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you here. Statement 1 is a copy of yours plus the DISTINCT keyword. How can there possibly be an invalid identifier? Statement 2 has two columns grouped by and three columns aggregated. I see no reason for the error you get. The last statement is yours, yes. It is just to demonstrate the better join syntax. Last thing: You seem unable to explain your problem. I sketched two scenarios. Which is yours?